# How to make VLC play a .vlm configuration file in "With no interface mode"?

Tags: windows, streaming, vlc-media-player, user-interface

How to make VLC play a [VLM configuration file](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/VLM#Configuration_Files) (`.vlm`) in "With no interface mode" on Windows?

So I have a VLM configuration file that should stream audio from mic to localhost so no VLC user interface is needed. If I say to Windows "play VLM file with VLC" it plays correctly, starts the server where I need and streams data. But how to do such a thing manually from the command line (so we suppose we can call `vlc.exe` by VLC and we are now in folder with the `vlc.exe` and `vlcConfig.vlm` files)?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
vlc.exe --vlm-conf=vlcConfig.vlm -I dummy
```